# Problem when using for loop with scikit-learn decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, bash, scikit-learn, dot

I'm trying to use scikit-learn tree library to draw decision trees by generating .dot files with tree.export_graphviz() function. I want to transform these .dot files into .pdf files using dot bash command line.

My python code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
from sklearn import tree
for i in range(3,10):
    clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=i)
    clf=clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
    file_name = 'tpsk1-' + str(i) + '.dot'
    tree.export_graphviz(clf,out_file=file_name)
```

In here, I'm writing a for loop with i from range 3 to 10 to export 7 dot files. But when I executed my bash script to transform them into pdf files, something weird happened.

My bash script:

```
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
        dot_file="tpsk1-$i.dot"
        pdf_file="tpsk1-$i.dot"
        dot -Tpdf $dot_file -o $pdf_file
done
```

The result:

```
Error: tpsk1-3.dot: syntax error in line 12 near '�S'
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '.0S' in line 12 of tpsk1-3.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '3r' in line 49 of tpsk1-3.dot splits into two tokens
Error: tpsk1-4.dot: syntax error in line 16 near 'X'
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '3r' in line 56 of tpsk1-4.dot splits into two tokens
Error: tpsk1-5.dot: syntax error in line 20 near 'ػ0'
Error: tpsk1-6.dot: syntax error in line 24 near '`'
Error: tpsk1-7.dot: syntax error in line 28 near '��'
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '1�' in line 31 of tpsk1-7.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '3r' in line 68 of tpsk1-7.dot splits into two tokens
Error: tpsk1-8.dot: syntax error in line 32 near '��'
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '0�' in line 32 of tpsk1-8.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '8z' in line 32 of tpsk1-8.dot splits into two tokens
Error: tpsk1-9.dot: syntax error in line 36 near '�Cb'
```

I retried to remove the for loop to write one single dot file and it worked just fine.

My new python script:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
from sklearn import tree
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3)
clf=clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
file_name = 'tpsk1-3.dot'
tree.export_graphviz(clf,out_file=file_name)
```

My dot bash command:

```
dot -Tpdf tpsk1-3.dot -o tpsk1-3.pdf
```

Can somebody please explain to me what happened, I think that I miss some wisdom behind for loop in python in here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong extension in your example:

```
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
        dot_file="tpsk1-$i.dot"
        pdf_file="tpsk1-$i.dot"
        dot -Tpdf $dot_file -o $pdf_file
done
```

It should be `pdf_file="tpsk1-$i.pdf"`